# Server data sent and receive

Tags: java, php, android

I was wondering if there is any another way to send and receive data from server without using php script. I know the php script approach but still wondering if any other method is available or not. 
Like i created a chatapp and i am sending and receiving data using php. But if it seems to slow down the process wondering if any one could help me with approach or tutorial thanks in advance.

Comment: why vote down can some one explain. I just asked simple question answer it or ignore dont vote down..

Comment: Society is the best approach. you can create socket using every language. (no down vote from me)

Comment: This question does *not* ask for a specific tool or library, it only asks if there are alternatives to PHP. This is a perfectly legitimate question to ask, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need a webservice to communicate.I don't think you can do it without an intermediate (Just imagine . How will you authenticate your chat user ?). Efficiently reuse code and check if there are any memory leaks. Also, get a good webserver(that really matters).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it is not a chat app. But kinda works that way. In this app A Co-ordinator send some data. and users at the other end can only receive that data but not reply. Using php is ok but bit of boring way as my emulator some how unable to receive data from server but can send easily. So i decided to ask whether any another approach is available. But somehow some people find this question inappropriate and down vote for me. Still thanks for help.

Comment: Yeah this is common on SO. This question doesn't require a downvote., I am voting up.